# O que significa " :: " em PHP?

Tags: php

Em PHP, o que significa esses quatro pontinhos "::" ?

Eu vejo muito em coisas como: stackOverflow::class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Esses quatro pontinhos significa que você está chamando um método estático de uma classe. Um método estático pode ser chamado sem a necessidade de instanciar um objeto da classe. Ex:

```
Class teste() {
  public function metodoTradicional() {
    echo 'Tradicional';
  }
  public static function metodoEstatico() {
    echo 'Estático';
  }
}

teste::metodoTradicional(); // vai dar erro
teste::metodoEstatico(); // vai imprimir 'Estático'
```

Mais sobre métodos estáticos você pode ler na documentação oficial: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Entendi, massa demais! Valeu.